# Global state for server side rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

Let's say I have a button and onclick it changes components state to timer, so its state goes from 5 to 4,3,2,1 every second but if page is refreshed the value is lost since it is not stored anywhere and is rendering on client side.

How can I make this function value not to be lost when page is refreshed and be broadcasted to all users.
I do not want to use database since this function will be used a lot and would slow the db connection network also there might be a delay on database and timer would not update and server respond in time.
Any other method?

Answer (score 0):

You need a server. You might not need a database, but if you're trying to share a global state, it needs to be stored somewhere that is not just a webpage. I'd suggest [websockets](https://javascript.info/websocket). Every user could connect to your server, and when any of them hits the button, they'll all be informed, you can then kick off the timer in each browser, or send out second events from the websocket.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say the timer is the same for all users. Really all you need to be storing server-side is a value for time zero. If you don't need to persist that value over server restarts (which needs a database), it could simply be a value in memory on the server. All the client needs then is to download this timer end value, and it can show the ticking client side by using a timeout.